# Send email on certain dates found in Mongo db using MailGun on MEAN Stack

Tags: mongodb, express, cron, mean

I need to send some emails on birthdays and certain other events such as event coming up soon or listing about to expire but I am not sure of the best way to go about doing this in MEAN stack.

Should I create another app and use forever to go through the database on daily basis or implement something like a Cron Job?

This is my first app in node and loving it so far :) NPM FTW!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update: Full tutorial [here](https://medium.com/@timsvoice/setup-a-scheduled-mailing-in-your-node-app-using-mailgun-and-node-schedule-416ac521cd3d).

You can do this right in your mean app, using a server controller and some npm packages.

The two best packages I know for integrating scheduled mail into node app are [node-schedule](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule) and [mailgun-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mailgun-js).

You will need 3 functions: A `mailSender` function, a `userSearch` function and a `scheduler` function.

Your mailgun email function is pretty straightforward:

```
var mailSender = function (user, subject, html, callback) {
    var mailgun = new Mailgun({apiKey: mailgun_api, domain: mailgun_domain});

    var data = {
      from: 'mail@yourdomain.com',
      to: user.email,
      subject:  subject,
      html: html,
      // nifty test mode flag
      // 'o:testmode': true
    };

    mailgun.messages().send(data, function (err, body) {
      //handle errors and body
    }); 
};
```

This will fire off an email to the `user.email` you pass to the function. The `html` can be an inline template or a path to a file.

Now you want to find users who have birthday (or other event). Best is to use the mongoose `find()` query and pass in a parameter from your user model and setting a variable to equal today's date. Your `userSearch` function should contain something like this (remember it's asnyc so you will need callbacks or promises to pass the data to another function):

```
  User.find().where('birthday').equals(today).exec(    
    function(err, user){        
    var users = [];
    // handle error
    if (err) return console.log(err);
    for (var i = user.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {        
        users.push(user[i]);
      } 
    return users;
  });
```

Using the `node-scheduler` package scheduling is also straightforward. You pass in a rule and as long as your app is running, it will fire. Rules look like this:

```
  var rule = new schedule.RecurrenceRule();
      rule.dayOfWeek = [new schedule.Range(0, 6)];
      rule.hour = 12;
      rule.minute = 30;
```

Here your rule is to fire every day at 12:30PM.
You then pass your rule to the `scheduleJob` method:

```
  // fire your scheduled task given the rules above
  var j = schedule.scheduleJob(rule, function(){
      // whatever function  you want the job to trigger
  }
```

Your function above will probably combine your `userSearch` function and your `mailSender` function. Remember that your `userSearch` is asynchronous, so you will need to use callbacks or promises to pass the user data into your `sendMailer` function.

**Pro Tip:**

MEAN comes with Swig for parsing `html` templates so use that to format your email. Something like this:

```
var email = swig.renderFile('app/views/templates/email.inlined.template.html', {
        //pass in your template variables
});
```

and pass that into your `mailSender` function.

Comment: Thanks for your excellent write up! Excellent tip for Swig ;)

Comment: One quick question. Since I will be using PM2 and will have 2 or 4 nodes running I guess I will need to limit scheduler only to one instance correct?

Comment: I don't have any direct experience with PM2 but if you run into issues, post back here so I can add to the answer.